# How to automatically react to DOM changes?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming

I have a list of items in the DOM:

```
<ul id="my_list">
    <li class="relevant">item 1 <a onclick="remove(1)">Remove</a></li>
    <li class="relevant">item 2 <a onclick="remove(2)">Remove</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

The user can remove items from the list by clicking the respective 'remove' links in the item.
I want to reactively monitor this list for changes, so that when there are no items left it triggers a function. For example:

```
var num_list_items = $("#my_list li.relevant").length;
if( num_list_items == 0 ){
    do_something();
}
```

My app is being built in Meteor, so would ideally like to know if there is any native functionality that can do this. If not, any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Note DOM L4 introduces `Element.prototype.remove`. That method is available is the scope of the anchor, so it will shadow your global `window.shadow` which removes the list item.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `MutationObserver`([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver))

You'll instantiate one with something to do everytime the observed node mutates, if the mutation reports the desired condition you'll do something about it.

```
var observed = document.getElementById('my_list');
var whatIsObserved = { childList : true };
var mo = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
       if(mutation.type === 'childList'){
          //DOM Tree mutated
          if(mutated.target.querySelectorAll('li.relevant').length === 0){
             //mutated target has no childs.
          }
       }
    });
});
mo.observe(observed, whatIsObserved);
```

Alternatively, have the `remove` function trigger your condition.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I needed to target specific <li> tags - only those with the class 'relevant. (I have edited question to reflect this).

Comment: I think I might have an idea of what you mean, so I've updated the answer. Also, you are free to use the same jQuery logic inside the mutation event.

Comment: Is it possible to also use a jQuery selector for the 'observed' var?

Comment: No, but you can get the selected element through [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/get/)